# Why do font files have to abide by CORS rules but images don't?

Tags: cors, font-face

When requesting font files cross-domain you have to ensure that the domain requesting is allowed to access the font file using CORS headers:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

However this isn't required when requesting images, either for `img` elements or `background-image`.

Why do these file types have different security?

Comment: Because that’s the way things have always been for images. In hindsight, if we had it to do over again, images also should have had same-origin  restrictions from the very beginning. But we can’t change it now because doing so would have the effect of breaking gazillions of existing sites.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Good point - you could argue new image file extensions should start abiding CORS rules.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on the links @Marged provided, browsers enforce CORS on font files because [the spec says](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#same-origin-restriction) that they must do so:

> For font loads, user agents must use the potentially CORS-enabled fetch method defined by the [FETCH] specification for URL's defined within @font-face rules. When fetching, user agents must use "Anonymous" mode, set the referrer source to the stylesheet's URL and set the origin to the URL of the containing document.

…and notes directly:

> The implications of this for authors are that fonts will typically not be loaded cross-origin […]

That doesn't really answer your question though, since the spec itself doesn't give the rationale for **why** this requirement had to be there.

The linked Firefox thread is one of many discussions, and mentions a general ["improved security for new specs"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604421#c21) rationale:

> There's a larger discussion here of what "new" resource types should
>   default to, whether they should simply default to the same unrestricted
>   linking allowed for images and script or whether they should be restricted by default with the ability to relax via CORS

But it sounds like in this particular case, the driving reason was political. That is, it factored in concerns which were not "purely technical". As one of the implementers [summarized](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604421#c9):

> The primary reason is that font vendors want Web authors to limit use of fonts to their own sites, and Web authors can't easily and reliably do that unless we provide a same-origin restriction by default.

This is corroborated in the bug tracker discussions of [other implementers](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86817#c2) as well, e.g.:

> The main effects of [a browser] not doing so, as far as I can see, are sites inadvertently violating their font licenses and authors being confused about the proper way to deploy fonts.