# javascript modules and CORS

Tags: javascript, module, cors

I am trying to understand modules in JavaScript but when I try to write a very simple module I get CORS error.I am using bracket as my text editor and the odd part is when I'm using live preview in brackets the code works but when I normally open the `.js` file I get error.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> JS </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import {add} from './libA.js'; 
            console.log(add(10,20));
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

libA.js

```
export function add(a,b) {
        return a+b ;
    }
```

*I get this error ->

```
Access to Script at 'file:///F:/WEB%20DEV/JavaScript/libA.js' from origin `null` has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Invalid response. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

(I even tried the latest version of chrome too)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Many browsers do not allow you to access files on the local filesystem with JavaScript (even if the HTML document is also on the local filesystem).

This extends to loading JavaScript *modules*.

Install a webserver and use that (with a URL like `http://localhost/`) for testing.

Comment: tnx .. but if I use webpack or babel is it possible to my module works ?

Comment: @AhmadReza — They rewrite your code so it doesn't use modules, so the restrictions imposed on module code by browsers don't apply.

Comment: This worked for me, used express to serve my page statically.

Comment: But browsers do allow access to those files via `<script>` without `type="module"`. Why are modules any different?

Comment: @dkniffin I imagine it is just The Powers That Be adding in restrictions they **would** have added in the first place (if they knew back then, what they know now). 

So, `type=module` is subject to CORS, but ordinary `script` loading is not (to avoid breaking existing sites). This is a nice article on the matter: https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/. 

(PS. Same with how `video`/`audio` avoid CORS, but fetching fonts requires it—the standard for  `video`/`audio`  was published before CORS became a standard, and then they couldn't enforce it on  `video`/`audio`  without breaking the web)

Comment: PS. on fonts (as media) being subject to CORS—may have been a political decision, as per natevw answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208474/why-do-font-files-have-to-abide-by-cors-rules-but-images-dont

> ("The primary reason is that font vendors want Web authors to limit use of fonts to their own sites, and Web authors can't easily and reliably do that unless we provide a same-origin restriction by default.")

Answer (score 7):

If you have node installed I would recommend installing [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) package. You'll be up and running in no time! Fixed my problem and I can run my application in chrome using the server.

Comment: Please elaborate !

Comment: *Please elaborate !* ~ * ~ Instead of **http-server** you may want to try **live-server**. See for example [install and run a local web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533794).

Answer (score -2):

I had the same, removed the type="module" and then the error was gone. Not sure why.

Comment: If you remove `type=“module”` then the JS will throw an error when it hits `import`

Comment: @Quentin how do you `import` (so ES6 code doesn't complain about missing class) and not get CORS ? I can `<script src="../somefile.js">` and load just fine, but can't import the same file to get the classes in my main html script `type="module"` section

Comment: It work form me in this case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77668054/load-angularjs-web-from-local-file-system