# Access to script blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, cors

I am making a simple test project including 2 JavaScript files , where i export and import modules , as shown below .

However ,when opening html page , an error generated in the console shows that :

> ```
>  Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/index2.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy 
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED      (index2.js:1)
> ```

I tried to desactivate CORS but that leads always to the same error , i am using Google Chrome browser .

what is abnormal in code and what to do to resolve this problem ?

**index2.js :**

```
export default class test {

 static method () {
   return ('hello world' ) ; 
}
```

**index.js :**

```
import test from './index2.js'; 

console.log (test.method())  ;
```

in **index.html :**

```
<script type = "module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you using any build tool? webpack etc.?

Comment: Most browsers don't allow you to access files on the local filesystem using JS. You will need to setup a local webserver and access the files from there. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50197495/5347875

Comment: aviya.developer no i didn't use a build tool in this example , @Daniel.Schroeder any suggestions ? thanks .

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem by setting up a local webserver , I Used **XAMPP** , the link below shows the installation and usage :

https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-web-server-all-platforms/

Comment: XAMPP is arguably the wrong solution. It's a giant product that requires configuration and only serves specific preconfigured directories. [Use one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver). They are lightweight and serve any folder instantly. No experienced web developer would use XAMPP for this situation.