# Error during Running module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, module, frontend

when I write the `type="module"` it shows this errors:

HTML code:
`<script type="module" defer src="main.js"></script>`

[image]

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197495/javascript-modules-and-cors).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript modules and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197495/javascript-modules-and-cors)

Comment: Thanks @Revive, I've gone ahead and marked this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install webserver to run the modules. I would like to suggest to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)