# Uncaught Reference Error , method not defined

Tags: javascript, import, module

I am trying to use a method from a javascript module and i dont understand why i get this error :

> index.html:5
>
> ```
>    Uncaught ReferenceError: starts is not defined
> at window.onload (index.html:5:11)
> ```

I have 2 `js` files and a `html` one and all are in the same folder.

**connect.js**

```
function start(){
    console.log("ok");
}
```

**main.js**

```
import{start} from './connect.js';
export{starts};
function starts(){
    start();
    console.log("started script");
}
```

**`Index.html`**

```
<html>
    <body>
       <script type="text/javascript"   >
        window.onload=function(ev){
          starts();
        };
       </script>
    </body>
   
    <script type="module"   src="./connect.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use modules from the local filesystem (by directly opening `index.html`), this is not allowed due to CORS restrictions. See this for more details: [javascript modules and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197495/javascript-modules-and-cors)

If there are no other project requirements regarding the use of modules, you may use the scripts without `type="module"` and remove import/export statements from `main.js`. Otherwise, you would need a server.

Answer (score -1):

You have made a spelling mistake in second line of your main.js
Use export{start} instead of export{starts}; And also change that in HTML file.

Comment: It is no spelling mistake. The `starts` ( in the `main.js`)  is called by the html , which in turn calls the `start` from the `connect.js`