# Chart.js and javascript within Flask webapp

Tags: javascript, html, flask, chart.js

I am working on a Flask application and I am attempting to use Chart.js within a JavaScript file.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="lineChart" width="900" height="400"></canvas>

    <script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/graph.js') }}"></script>
    
    <!--script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
      var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: {{ labels | safe }},
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data Points",
              data: {{ values | safe }}, 
              fill: false,
              borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
              lineTension: 0.1
            }
          ]
        },
      options: {
        responsive: false
      }
      });
      
  </script-->
  </body>
</html>
```

The line Chart displays correctly with the commented out section (and the line importing graph.js is commented out)

However when I try to create the chart within the graph.js file, the chart is not displayed at all. My JS code is below:

```
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js";

var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
      var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: {{ labels | safe }},
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data Points",
              data: {{ values | safe }}, 
              fill: false,
              borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
              lineTension: 0.1
            }
          ]
        },
      options: {
        responsive: false
      }
      });
}
```

graph.js is loading fine. I believe the problem lies in importing Chart.js into the JavaScript file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: This code is from a simple app I built for testing the methods I will implement in the real app. The code was taken from teclado on youtube and modified slightly to mirror the real app

Comment: Did you mean `<!--script>`, or `<!-- script -->`?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and I get CORS Policy Blocking JS modules from my browser.
That could be the reason for you when you are trying to import Chart.js into the Javascript file.

If you also get that, this solution recommends the use of a webserver [javascript modules and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197495/javascript-modules-and-cors)

I was also trying to find examples with Flask and Chart.js and the Javascript code is always located in the `<script>` tag in the .html file.

Some examples:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-a-flask-web-app-by-scraping-a-website-display-the-data-using-chart-js-bd0c97397967
https://www.codementor.io/@chirilovadrian360/flask-charts-js-via-flask-restx-with-sample-1so96nk2dt

Hope this information helps you.